# angular form data won't append

Tags: angular, form-data

I am trying to upload files with angular 6. However, I can't seem to append my formData(). Alittle help. Thank you.

home.component.ts

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedFile: File = null;
constructor(
private _route: ActivatedRoute,
private _router: Router,
private _postService: PostService
) { }

ngOnInit() {}


onFileChanged(event) {
this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0]}

postImage() {
const uploadData = new FormData();
uploadData.append('myFile', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
console.log(uploadData)
this._postService.postImage(uploadData)}}
```

home.component.html

```
<input style="display: none" type="file (change)="onFileChanged($event)" #fileInput>
<button (click)="fileInput.click()">Select File</button>
<button (click)="postImage()">Upload!</button>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try something like this:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6msxcf)

The file is already appended in `formdata` but You can not directly inspect form data :

```
onFileChanged(event) {

    let formData = new FormData();
    this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
    this.currentFileUpload = this.selectedFiles.item(0);


    console.log(this.currentFileUpload)
    formData.append('file', this.currentFileUpload);

    formData.append('labelName', 'test');
    formData.append('formPart', 'test');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(formData))

   formData.forEach((value,key) => {
      console.log(key+" "+value)
    });
  }
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I didn't use a middleware for receiving files on my backend. But I "fixed" it right after I used multer, and I can see the file being uploaded. Thank you for the response.