# FormData.append() appears to not be adding items

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, form-data

I am working on a project using Angular and Node for a job I am training for and am currently stuck trying to fix what appears to be my own misunderstanding of the FormData data type. I have isolated the problem to the following code:

```
const postData = new FormData();
        postData.append("title", title);
        postData.append("content", content);
        this.http
          .post<{ message: string; post: Post }>(
            "http://localhost:3000/api/posts",
            postData
          )
```

Before this code is run, the variables that supply the data to the FormData contain the correct information, but on the backend the parameters come up undefined. Attempts to peer into the FormData are causing CORS errors that appear in no other contexts. Any help either letting me see into the FormData, better verifying what is happening on the backend, or using FormData in general would be appreciated.

Comment: I've seen similar issues and would love to know why this occurs.

Comment: Have you tried sending Content-Type headers with the request? 
`Content-Type: multipart/form-data`

Comment: What is the value of `postData` before you send it to the API but after you've appended what you want? Please include the API request payload and response payload also. Instructions on inspecting the formData: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52031766/angular-form-data-wont-append

Comment: Also, you don't need to add content headers to FormData payloads in Angular as @ArslanShahab suggests, Angular will insert the correct headers based on the payload type.